# VSCode terminate task by name

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I created a VSCode extension and run successfully a task by its name, like:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.tasks.runTask", "task_name_here");
```

now, when I try to terminate that task by name, the UI keeps asking me to select the task manually:

```ts
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.action.tasks.terminate", "task_name_here");
```

Is there a way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[As of VSCode 1.24](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49806), there is an API that lets you do this. You can register event listeners for things like tasks being started / ending, and those events all contain a `TaskExecution` instance. On top of that, there is a read-only list that contains all current executions. An execution is defined like [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/32bdc37eb3a9ea833d6acb02087630da311ba97a/src/vs/vscode.proposed.d.ts#L337-L353):

```ts
/**
 * An object representing an executed Task. It can be used
 * to terminate a task.
 *
 * This interface is not intended to be implemented.
 */
export interface TaskExecution {
    /**
     * The task that got started.
     */
    task: Task;

    /**
     * Terminates the task execution.
     */
    terminate(): void;
}
```